# SmartCardIO EMV Reader, find my card type with only the ATR number

Tags: java, smartcard, emv

I´m starting a new project, I´m new using EMV reader and Javax SmartCardIO.

I have the list of the RID for each type of card, however the only thing I can access without knowing the type of card is the ATR, I´m wondering if there is a way to get the RID or the card type with only this info, any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I tried to execute the select PSE command with this method:

```
public static byte[] selectPSE(CardChannel channel) throws CardException {
    byte[] selectPSE = {(byte)0x00, (byte)0xA4, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x0E, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x50, (byte)0x41, (byte)0x59, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x53, (byte)0x59, (byte)0x53, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x44, (byte)0x44, (byte)0x46, (byte)0x30, (byte)0x31};
    CommandAPDU command = new CommandAPDU(selectPSE);
    ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(command);
    System.out.println(response.getBytes());
    return response.getBytes();
}
```

However, It is only working with an AMEX and Visa, I´m getting the error 6a82 with two MasterCard Cards(credit and debit).

This looks very strange, as far as I know all the major card issuers (including MasterCard) use 1PAY.SYS.DDF01, I can get the information I want with Try and Error of the AID but I don´t think this is the best solution.

Comment: Are you trying to read EMV card data, please define your purpose in detail.

Comment: Yes, I´m trying to create an application which identifies and displays all the data from a smart card.

Answer (score 6):

AID (Application ID) = RID(Registered Application ID) || PIX (Property Application Extension)

The best way how to recognize what application is installed on card - make **Select PSE**. Detailed description in [EMV Book 1, 12 Application Selection, 12.3.2 Using the PSE](https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223).

Full algorithm you can find on Figure 17: Terminal Logic Using Directories.

Quick algorithm:

1) Command **Select** PSE or PPSE.

```
  Send: 00 A4 04 00 0E 31 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 00

  Responce will will contain:
   '6F' FCI Template M
      '84' DF Name M
      'A5' FCI Proprietary Template M
        '88' SFI of the Directory Elementary File M
        '5F2D' Language Preference O
        '9F11' Issuer Code Table Index O
        'BF0C' FCI Issuer Discretionary Data O
```

Here you can find **SFI** of PSE.

2) Command **ReadRecord** 1 SFI X

```
 Send: 00 B2 01 0C 00

  Receive list of tag. 
   '70' Application Elementary File (AEF) Data Template                
      '61' Application Template                                           
        '70' Application Elementary File (AEF) Data Template                
          '61' Application Template                                           
            '4F' Application Identifier (AID)
            '50' Application Label
            ...  and so on
```

Look there for **Tag '4F'** Application Identifier (AID). From it you can extract and compare RID.

Аlso you can:

1) Get own list of AID and successively SELECT application from it.

2) SELECT Default or Next applications and get AID from response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am testing the appliation with an AMEX, and two MasterCards(Debit and Credit), the command is only working with the AMEX, as far as I understand this 1PAY.SYS.DDF01 command should be available in all three cards right? I´m editing my post with the results

Comment: PSE can be absent on card, it's usual situation. I suppose, you got responce from card SW=0x6A82 (instead 6a62) which means ‘File not found’. This is situation when PSE is absent. Follow Figure 17: Terminal Logic Using Directories. When PSE is not found- terminal (your code) should perform selection (Try and Error) from terminal (your own) AID list. 

But be careful, card may support Particle Selection. And when you direct select MasterCard A0000000041010, you may realy select instance A0000000041010000000  which you will see in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to get RID values from card with ATR. ATR is used to identify card hardware and software, it is not used to get info about installed applications(visa, visa electron, mastercard etc) https://eftlab.com/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/212-emv-rid

There is one way to get installed applications , reading Payment System Environment(PSE ) of card . You can send **Read PSE** commands to contact cards and **Read Proximity PSE** command for contactless cards

Contact PSE:

> 00A404000E315041592E5359532E4444463031

Contactless PPSE:

> 00A404000E325041592E5359532E444446303100

And then you must parse if there is more than one installed application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am testing the appliation with an AMEX, and two MasterCards(Debit and Credit), the command is only working with the AMEX, as far as I understand this 1PAY.SYS.DDF01 command should be available in all three cards right? I´m editing my post with the results

Comment: If those cards are contactless you must send "Read PPSE" command. If you are sure they are contact cards,  there should be another problem. Some cards does not support read PSE command, they only contain one application and allow to select directly it. This is called explicit selection. For those cards "select pse" will not work